# Prove $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $Y$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Let $X, Y$ be two homeomorphic topological spaces. Prove $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $Y$ is Hausdorff

My attempt:

Let $ f: X \to Y $ be the homeomorphism between the two and $ X $ is Hausdorff, to see that $ Y $ is also Hausdorff, let's take two points $ y, y^\prime\in Y $ different let's take it to $ X $ by $ f^{-1}  $;
How can I separate them for open? (because $ X $ is Hausdorff) and transfer them to open that separate $y,y^\prime$  using $ f $.

How would it be if $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: Remember that homeomorphisms are *bijections*. Take $y_1\not=y_2\in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y_1)\not=f^{-1}(y_2)\in X$, so you can separate them with disjoint open sets $U_1,U_2\subset X$ since $X$ is Hausdorff. Then $f(U_1)$ and $f(U_2)$ are disjoint opens in $Y$ that separate $y_1$ and $y_2$. The argument for $y$ is very similar, it's the same proof but replacing $f$ with its inverse $f^{-1}$. Can you fill in the details?

Comment: A homeomorphism is an open map. So it's easy to transfer open sets in $X$ to $Y$ (just take their image).

Comment: Here's my intuition for problems like this: a homeomorphism just systematically gives different names to the points in a space. Properties like the Hausdorff property are independent of the details of how the points are named - if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic you can transfer the statement that $X$ is Hausdorff to the statement that $Y$ is Hausdorff just by applying the renaming to all the points involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x,x'\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ and that $f(x')=y'$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there are neighborhoods $V$ of $x$ and $V'$ of $x'$ which do not intersect. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, $f(V)$ and $f(V')$ are neighborhoods of $y$ and of $y'$ respectively. But, since $V\cap V'=\emptyset$ and $f$ is a bijection, $f(V)\cap f(V')=\emptyset$ too.